# disabling and rendering components using by private boolean - other way

Tags: java, jsf

i have a cosmetic problem. I'm using

```
private boolean production = true;
```

(+ getters and setters)

for inner logic of application. And in the JSF I'm calling it for rendering or disabling components, for example

```
<h:commandButton id="f1" action="#{bean.save}" type="submit" disabled="#{bean.production}"/>
```

And it works. But it seems to me a bit ugly.

Is there some other way to achieve the same functionality?

Thank you

Comment: what is the functionality you are looking to achieve differently? If it's rendering or disabling components based on the value of a backing bean then this seems like a standard way to accomplish the task to me, but maybe you're looking for a more elegant solution to a larger problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for more elegant solution. Because JSF wants it private + getters and setters, and the other JAVA class wants it private STATIC + get, sets. So I sometimes need to use two booleans for one thing and it makes a bit of mess...

Comment: what does production represent? Is it something that you can make global through JNDI via a static method for access throughout the app. If so you can just drop the private member of the bean and the setter method and change getProduction() to call the same static method and return the value. Not sure if that's where you are going though.

Comment: Production variable only represents choosed variant of adding work by worker to database using my intranet application. The other choice is for example Delay. I'm newbie so I don't know, what for the JNDI is. But the solution you've suggested doesn't work for me, if i undestood it well

Comment: So basically the problem you want to solve is not having two different variables that represent the same thing in the app? One a private boolean on a jsf backing bean and other a private static member of some other class. Am I now understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: k. see BalusC below. Just delegate in the JSF bean method. You don't actually need a private member or a setter on the JSF bean since you are only reading the value in your view.

Comment: Thank you too, I've only need to see it written exactly as BalusC did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'm looking for more elegant solution. Because JSF wants it private + getters and setters, and the other JAVA class wants it private STATIC + get, sets. So I sometimes need to use two booleans for one thing and it makes a bit of mess...*

Just let the JSF bean getter delegate. E.g.

```
public boolean isProduction() {
    return Settings.PRODUCTION;
}
```

This way you end up with only one variable containing the value, namely `Settings.PRODUCTION`. You can even decouple it from the request/view scoped bean and wrap it in an application scoped managed bean. Even more, if you let it extend `Map` and put the values upon construction, then you'll be able to use something like `disabled="#{settings['PRODUCTION']}"`.

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean(name="settings", eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class SettingsManager extends HashMap<String, Object> {

    public SettingsManager() {
        put("PRODUCTION", Settings.PRODUCTION);
        put("DEBUG", Settings.DEBUG);
        put("HOSTNAME", Settings.HOSTNAME);
        // ...
    }

}
```

If you're still on JSF 1.x, remove those annotations and map it as follows in `faces-config.xml`.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>settings</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.SettingsManager</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: Thank you again, that's all I need in this case :)

Comment: And that's I looked for when I asked my question, I'll try it! Thanks

Comment: Ehm, can you advise me how to create the map?:] I don't know where to start

Comment: I added an example to answer.

Comment: I've tried thi first SettingsManager and there is HashMap<String, String>, but the settings.PRODUCTION is boolean. Trying HashMap<String, Boolean> doesn't work. It seems I'm too old for programming :/

Comment: Oh sorry, make it `Object` :)

Comment: With the Object is it the same as with the Boolean as I tried before - disabled="#{settings['PRODUCTION']}" do nothing...

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in the key. `PRODUCTON` instead of `PRODUCTION`. Anyway .. what do you see if you just do `#{settings}` in EL? Do you see the result of `Map#toString()`? Are you using JSF 1.x or JSF 2.x? Those `@` annotations are JSF 2.x only. On JSF 1.x you need to declare the bean as an application scoped bean in `faces-config.xml`.

Comment: PRODUCTON - this is it :D.... #{settings['PRODUCTION']} now works, but the last thing is, that PRODUCTION is defined as public static boolean in Settings class. And so it have still the same value and switching (DISABLE/ENABLE) doesn't work

Comment: Reasonable. Those are thus not really one-time-initialized constants. You would need to wrap them in getters instead of copying them, or to change the `Settings` class itself so that the values are stored in a map and the class itself is eligible to be used as an application scoped bean.

Comment: Wrapping them into getters doesn't help, but it seems to be too late for thinking or what, so I'll do not disturb you longer. Anyway, thanks for your substantial help!!

Comment: I mean, just an application scoped bean which does not extend `Map`, but just have getters like `isProduction()` etc. Like as I have shown in the initial answer.

Comment: Yep, it works very fine, but excludes the elegant solution with HashMap :)))