# JSF/JAVA boolean switchers (private for JSF, public static for Beans)

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm using boolean switchers to resolve a choosed behaviour of application, for example SAVEACCEPTED enables SAVE button of form.

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.save}" disabled="#{!bean.saveaccepted}">
```

JSF need private boolean and its getters and setters, but if I want to resolve some internal logic in application server, it must be defined static. For example

```
IF (USERFOUND) SAVEACCEPTED = true;
```

So, I'm using [settings class and there are public static booleans defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914200/disabling-and-rendering-components-using-by-private-boolean-other-way). And in the beans there are getters and setters pointing to the Settings.VARIABLE

Settings.java

```
public static boolean SAVEACCEPTED = false;
```

Bean.java

```
public static boolean isSaveAccepted() {
  return Settings.SAVEACCEPTED;
}
```

Problem is, that the public boolean is only one and if more then one users using an application, when the first switch the variable, it affects second user form.

How can I solve this issue, is there some standard solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `static` variable. Use a [`@SessionScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) or [`@ViewScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) bean to store the settings separately for each user.

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Settings
{
    private boolean saveAccepted = false;
    
    public boolean isSaveAccepted()
    {
        return saveAccepted;
    }
    
    public void setSaveAccepted(boolean saveAccepted)
    {
        this.saveAccepted = saveAccepted;
    }
}
```

and

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.save}" disabled="#{!settings.saveaccepted}">
```

---

> What if i'd need to set the saveAccepted = true in another bean (not in JSF)? It doesn't work, because in that case, saveAccepted have to be static.

#### Do **not** use a static variable.

If you need to set the value in another bean, you can [`@Inject`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) an instance:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SomeOtherBean
{
    @Inject
    private Settings settings;
    
    public boolean getSaveAccepted()
    {
        return settings.getSaveAccepted();
    }
    
    public void setSaveAccepted(boolean saveAccepted)
    {
        settings.setSaveAccepted(saveAccepted);
    }
}
```

and [CDI](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnr.html) will give you the right instance of `Settings`.

---

[BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) comments:

> Based on the question history, OP is using Tomcat which is just a simple servletcontainer.

Since it looks like you're not using a full Java EE 6 container, you can use `@ManagedBean` instead of `@Named` and `@ManagedProperty` instead of `@Inject`.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SomeOtherBean
{
    @ManagedProperty
    private Settings settings;
    
    public boolean getSaveAccepted()
    {
        return settings.getSaveAccepted();
    }
    
    public void setSaveAccepted(boolean saveAccepted)
    {
        settings.setSaveAccepted(saveAccepted);
    }
}
```

My apologies for sending you down a more complicated path!

Comment: Thanks, but what if i'd need to set the saveAccepted = true in another bean (not in JSF)? It doesn't work, because in that case, saveAccepted have to be static..:(

Comment: @gaffcz see my edit. You must give up using `static` for this.

Comment: Thank you, and how setup getters of injection?

Comment: You show me a setter for saveAccepted (inject), and I don't know how to construct getter..

Comment: Really? You'd just delegate the call the exact same way... see my edit.

Comment: Jj, i've tried it as you write now, but it reports java.lang.NullPointerException at common.MyBde.isProduction(MyBde.java:67), and there is return settings.isProduction(); inside getter

Comment: Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /bde.xhtml @155,224 disabled="#{myBDE.production or sessionScope['service']}": Error reading 'production' on type common.MyBde

Comment: You probably don't have CDI turned on. See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html

Comment: I've installed 3 CDI jars, javax.inject.jar and empty bean.xml to web-inf, repaired xhtml switchers from myBean.production to settings.production, but now doesn't work settings.setProduction(true); in java / nullpointexception...?

Comment: @Matt: based on the question history, OP is using Tomcat which is just a simple servletcontainer. @gaffcz: Just use `@ManagedBean`/`@ManagedProperty` instead.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, I should have though to check question history before sending OP down the CDI path. Edited accordingly.

Comment: @gaffcz, try BalusC's recommendation - use `@ManagedBean` instead of `@Named`, and use `@ManagedProperty` instead of `@Inject`. I've edited my answer accordingly, to help you out.

Comment: Thank you both, ManagedProperty works better, but it's horrible, rewriting whole application :]

Comment: Last questtion I hope, if I calling Settings bean from more then one other beans, should I name them differently? @ManagedProperty
(value={settingsA}); @ManagedProperty
(value={settingsB}), etc.?

Comment: Hmm, it really works in principal. But there is some problem using ajax, I don't know whay, but it works normally before, and now (after injection) it returns null (looking for object in dtb). I'll make a new question

Comment: It's not in ajax, but it setter, i can´t using it

Answer (score 2):

Using static variable in this scenario is not ideal. Static fields by definition are shared across all instances of the class. So what is happening is the value you are storing are getting shared for all instances of your managed bean.

I recommend you save it at the request scope with `@ViewScoped` or define it in the faces-config.xml with `<managed-bean-scope>`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not able to change the values in another bean.. it have to be static

Comment: @gaffcz - For you to access fields in another bean, you would need to inject that bean as a managed property for the other bean. That's how this is usually done.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying but it still doesn't work, take a look bellow, if you want :)

Comment: @gaffcz - could you please add to your post your set up currently? That should include web.xml, faces-config.xml and relevant snippets from xhtml and backing bean.