# @ManagedProperty in backing bean - setting getters and setters

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

According [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164078/jsf-java-boolean-switchers-private-for-jsf-public-static-for-beans), I've implemented `@ManagedProperty(value="#{settings}")` to my backing bean:

**BEAN Bde.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bdeDATA")
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name="BDE")
public class Bde implements Serializable
{
  /**/
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -705775502999920673L;

  @Transient
  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{settings}")
  private Settings settings;

  @Id
  private Date create_date;
  private Integer person_ID;

  public Date getCreate_date() {
    return create_date;
  }
  public void setCreate_date(Date create_date) {
    this.create_date = create_date;
  }
  public Integer getPerson_ID() {
    return person_ID;
  }
  public void setPerson_ID(Integer person_ID) {
    this.person_ID = person_ID;

    try 
    {
      Settings.PWKITEM = (Pwk)Tools.find(person_ID);
      if (Settings.PWKITEM != null) settings.setUserfound(true); /// PROBLEMATIC
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Tools.setErrorMessage("NOT FOUND "+e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  // ManagedProperty settings ---------------------------------------------  
  public Settings getSettings() {
    return settings;
  }
  public void setSettings(Settings settings) {
    this.settings = settings;
  }
  public void setUserfound (boolean userfound){
    settings.setUserfound(userfound);
  }
  public boolean isUserfound() {
    return settings.isUserfound();
  }
}
```

**Settings.java**:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="settings")
public class Settings implements Serializable
{
  /**/
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8613411699115714416L;

  public static Pwk PWKITEM = new Pwk(); 
  private boolean userfound = false;  

  public boolean isUserfound() {
    return userfound;
  }
  public void setUserfound(boolean userfound) {
    this.userfound = userfound;
  }
}
```

**XHTML** (ajax call setPerson_ID):

```
<h:inputText id="persId" value="#{bean.bdeitem.persId}">
  <f:ajax event="blur" render="name" execute="@this" />
</h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.pwkitem.name}"/>
```

Problem is in `try/catch`:

- without the condition, object is found.
- when I change the condition for example to `if (Settings.PWKITEM != null) System.out.println("HELLO")`, `HELLO` is writen to console.
- if i try to add the `userfound` setter, it is catched ("NOT FOUND").

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I find this scary. A static property in a session scoped bean? Isn't this supposed to be in an application scoped bean? Do you understand the lifespan of application/session/view/request scopes? Do you understand the meaning of `static`?

Comment: I thought I do, but now I see, I don't undersatnd it well. That's happening if I must do my bachelor work in time and I'm virgin in java :)

Comment: I would love to post an answer, but it isn't entirely clear to me what the functional requirement is. Are those settings user-specific or application specific? What is `userfound` supposed to represent? Whether someone is logged in? For who is this information supposed? The user itself? Or everyone visiting the webapp? And what does `PWKITEM` represent?

Comment: I've "solved" this issue morning as you can see at my own answer. `Userfound` is static boolean, which only tells, if the user has been found. This user is used on ajax call, if I put `personId` to inputtext, ajax calls the setter and it if user is found (bsed on personId), rest of properties of object PWKITEM are filled. It's very hard to explain for me - work can be saved only if user with personId exists in database

Comment: I have the impression that your application is not threadsafe. I.e. it will fail when multiple users use the same application simultaneously. I have also seen your another question where you completely misunderstood the session. This is a pretty serious problem. I think it's better to post the concrete functional requirements in your future questions instead of posting some piece of bad code and only telling about the problem instead of the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question looks seriously confusing. You first show some bean code and then immediately say "I though that is an ajax problem,", before even mentioning any kind of problem. The rest of the question is not much different.

To directly answer the last part of your question though:

> Ican't understand, why it find the item an writes the correct name to console, and immediatelly after that, it writes catch exception not found....????

You are accessing `Settings` statically. The instance you have declared at the class level seems to be useless. It's fully possible that if `Tools.find` throws an exception and thus no new value is assigned, that there is still an old value in the static `Settings.PWKITEM` field. There is nothing strange about that.

Do note that the log reads from top to bottom. So it's not that "***" is printed and then the exception is thrown, but the exception is first thrown and "Not Found" is printed, and only thereafter "***" is printed.

Additionally, your approach to all of this looks problematic. Declaring an Entity to also be a (JSF) backing bean is rarely a good idea. Using references to some kind of Service or DAO classes from within an entity is also not always a good idea, but doing this in a method that is supposedly a simple setter for an ID simply looks wrong.

Then using static references is even more wrong and to top if off, using underscores in method and non-static variable names goes against the common Java code convention.

Comment: Thanks, I'm changing it as I'm going forward in solution. It's mess, I know :-) It first time, I'm using @ManagedProperty and I'm little bit confused...

Comment: No offense intended whatsoever, but it shows. Good luck with learning and improving the code! We all had to start one day ;)